# Adding parameters to the init_per_testcase config parameter

Tags: erlang, common-test

I have a erlang integration test using the common test frame work. The config parameter passed to the init_per_testcase call and all the tests is initialized as:

```
ConfigFilename = filename:absname("something.config", os:getenv("TEST_DIR")),
config:load(ConfigFilename).
```

How can a I add a parameter to the config object, I would like to add a PID for a gen_server which all tests must use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a list of key value tuples so [{key,Value}|Config] did the trick.